# TSQL Distinct unique result set required but I get repeating values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

the following code for some bizarre reason gives me a value for each row in the table. I just want unique values :

```
public IQueryable<WasteIndicatorItem> FindAllEWC()
{

    var results = (from x in this._db.WasteIndicatorItems
                   orderby x.EWC
                   select x).ToList();



    return results.OrderBy(s => s.EWC).Distinct().AsQueryable();
}
```

I've tried moving the .Distinct() all over the place, before the ToList ETC. What am i doing wrong must be something simple, cheers for reading..

So in my results I get :

```
13
13
13
12345
12345
```

rather than :

```
13
12345
```

TABLE STRUCTURE IS :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WasteIndicatorItem](
    [WasteIndicatorItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WasteId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WasteIndicatorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EWC] [varchar](6) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [WasteHazardCodeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](4000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [EnteredById] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Entered] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedById] [int] NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IndicatorItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WasteIndicatorItemId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Use `GroupBy` and keep everything on the SQL side (preferred). You would group by the property you're interested in that defines uniqueness to you.
2. Use [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) to bring everything down, then use the [overloaded `Distinct` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) that accepts an `IEqualityComparer`. This usually isn't a good idea (unless the result set is small) since all the matching results are returned, and less processing is done on the SQL side.

Implementing the first solution looks like this:

```
var results = _db.WasteIndicatorItems
                 .OrderBy(x => x.EWC)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.EWC)
                 .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: This code block gives me the same result set, I debug and results contains many rows of same repeating data. I think group by is needed tho, any ideas? THANKS

Comment: Looking at the 'overloaded distinct method' example in the link it looks like i need to write a class. There must be a one line way of removing repeating data from this object. Seems convoluted for what I need. thanks but can you advise me a little further please, many  thanks

Comment: @John the values you posted in your question, are those `EWC` values? I used the ID, which will be unique anyway, so you'll need to use the property/column that you want to have distinct values for. I suspect that might be `EWC` so use `GroupBy(x => x.EWC)` instead (I've updated my answer). Also the `GroupBy` approach bypasses the need to write the `IEqualityComparer` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying Distinct to List but not EF DBSet. For sure each entry in List will be unique, unless you have defined IEquatable implementation.
So if you want discard duplicates on client side you have to implement IEquatable for data objects or you can use grouping in you query.

Answer (score 1):

Linq Distinct() does [not really behave as you might expect](http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct%28%29-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx).

You need to create an equality comparer and use it in the Union or Distinct ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869645/22194))

Or maybe try DistinctBy from the [MoreLinq library](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview)

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the items to be distinct on? By default - assuming you put the `Distinct()` call before materializing results and moving back to Linq to Objects by using `ToList()` - I would assume Entity Framework will look at the `WasteIndicatorItemId` which is your primary key and *by definition will be unique*, so your `Distinct` call will not change anything (and might even be optimized away).